# How to set a CoreOS cluster on VirtualBox?

Tags: coreos, coreos-ignition

I would like to set a coreOS cluster on VirtualBox. I have read the coreOS documentation in the oficial site and it is said I have to boot each virtual machine with the same configuration and they should be automatically clustered. 
I am using the ct command in order to translate the Container Linux Configuration into the coreOS ignition file.

> ct --platform=vagrant-virtualbox < containerLinuxConfig >
>   ignition.json

This is my container Linux Config file

```
etcd:
  name:                        "{HOSTNAME}"
  listen_peer_urls:            "http://{PRIVATE_IPV4}:2380"
  listen_client_urls:          "http://0.0.0.0:2379"
  initial_advertise_peer_urls: "http://{PRIVATE_IPV4}:2380"
  advertise_client_urls:       "http://{PRIVATE_IPV4}:2379"
  # replace "<token>" with a valid etcd discovery token
  discovery:                   "https://discovery.etcd.io/b89df44ae2643afed5d3f05ea774ba6b"

systemd:
  units:
    - name: docker-tcp.socket
      enable: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Docker Socket for the API

        [Socket]
        ListenStream=2375
        Service=docker.service
        BindIPv6Only=both

        [Install]
        WantedBy=sockets.target
    - name: flanneld.service
      dropins:
        - name: 50-network-config.conf
          contents: |
            [Service]
            ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/etcdctl set /flannel/network/config '{ "Network": "10.2.0.0/16", "Backend":{"Type":"vxlan"} }'

flannel:
  etcd_prefix: "/flannel/network"

passwd:
  users:
    - name: core-01
      password_hash: $1$B61gfKDk$ALsU28o4XGSro4Uqd00FW/
      groups:
        - sudo
        - docker
```

But when I boot the first virtual machine, I use the

> etcdctl member list

command in order to check if the first member of the cluster is up, I get this output.

```
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused
; error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connect: connection refused

error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused
error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connect: connection refused
```

When the output should be similar to

```
e601a65b304e868f: name=core-01 peerURLs=http://192.168.1.30:2380 clientURLs=http://192.168.1.30:2379 isLeader=true
```

Why is this happening? What I should change in the container linux configuration to get the machine clustered?

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like the etcd is taking default parameters. `127.0.0.1:2379` did you tried to specify the `${HOSTNAME}` and `${PRIVATE_IPV4}`
and consider this as well:

> `-–initial-cluster-state` Initial cluster state (“new” or “existing”).
>   Set to new for all members present during initial static or DNS
>   bootstrapping. If this option is set to existing, etcd will attempt to
>   join the existing cluster. If the wrong value is set, etcd will
>   attempt to start but fail safely. default: “new” env variable:
>   ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE

Refer to the bellow configuration. This will help you spin up a single etcd instance. 
you can skip the ssl certificates if you want.

```
etcd:
  version:                     3.2.17
  name:                        core-01
  data_dir:                    /var/lib/etcd
  listen_client_urls:          https://10.0.2.11:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://127.0.0.1:4001
  advertise_client_urls:       https://10.0.2.11:2379
  listen_peer_urls:            https://10.0.2.11:2380
  initial_advertise_peer_urls: https://10.0.2.11:2380
  initial_cluster:             core-01=https://10.0.2.11:2380
  initial_cluster_token:       etcd-token
  initial_cluster_state:       new
  cert_file:                   /var/lib/etcd/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client.pem
  key_file:                    /var/lib/etcd/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem
  peer_cert_file:              /var/lib/etcd/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client.pem
  peer_key_file:               /var/lib/etcd/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem
  client_cert_auth:            true
  peer_client_cert_auth:       true
  trusted_ca_file:             /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
  peer_trusted_ca_file:        /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
  auto_compaction_retention:   1
```

if you want to add more, just add the other node's IP address.

```
...             

initial_cluster: coreos1=https://10.0.0.4:2380,coreos2=https://10.0.0.5:2380,coreos3=https://10.0.0.6:2380

...
```